# Tagging convention for Touhou

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The four existing Touhou tags use three different naming conventions:

- [touhou-eosd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-eosd) identifies the game through the subtitle, Embodiment of Scarlet Devil.
- [touhou-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-7) uses the game's number, but ignores the subtitle, Perfect Cherry Blossom.
- [touhou-7.5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-7.5) is the same, not using Immaterial and Missing Power in its name.
- [touhou-12.8-fairy-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-12.8-fairy-wars) tries to fit everything, shortening the subtitle of Great Fairy Wars

I'd like to see a standard convention put in place for this series, given that the games are referred to both by number and subtitle.

Some background for those unfamiliar with the naming convention: the games' titles are entirely in Japanese, the subtitles are in English, and each title is ordered by an accompanying number, though the number is not found in the title itself.

As an example, the sixth game in the series is named "Touhou Koumakyou ~ the Embodiment of Scarlet Devil"; the most common way to refer to it is "Embodiment of Scarlet Devil", or simply "EoSD", but "Touhou 6" would be recognized just as easily by most players.

As Justin Time mentioned in the comments, there are a few exceptions to this:
12.3 has the full name of "Touhou Hisoutensoku ~ Choudokyuu Ginyoru no Nazo wo Oe", and English fans usually call it either "Unthinkable Natural Law", from the English translation of its Japanese subtitle, or "Hisoutensoku".
12.8 is "Yousei Daisensou ~ Touhou Sangetsusei", and English fans usually call it "Great Fairy Wars", "Fairy Wars", or (with tongue firmly in cheek) ["Faily Wars"](https://en.touhouwiki.net/images/4/4c/Th128FailyWarsTypo.jpg).
12.5 is "Double Spoiler ~ Touhou Bunkachou", with an English title and Japanese subtitle.

Comment: How does the Touhou community and/or the game devs typically refer to these games? For searchability, that's probably what we should aim for.

Comment: @MageXy I've edited some information in

Comment: Based on what you've edited in, I would personally go for the first style ([touhou-subtitle]), because I feel like that is more easily and quickly identifiable than a number. (For example, I still find it mildly difficult to tell Final Fantasy games apart by just number. I always have to do a short mental hop to recall specifics.) However, I've never played any of the Touhou games so I don't feel confident in actually giving an answer.

Comment: @MageXy From what I gather, the English fans usually use the (English) subtitle, the Japanese fans usually use the (Japanese) title, and I have no idea what fans that don't speak either of these languages do.  The numbers are sometimes used, too (more frequently for the side games (the ones with decimals in the number)), but I don't believe they're used as often as the title or subtitle.

Comment: There are a few exceptions to this, too: 12.3 has the full name of _Touhou Hisoutensoku ~ Choudokyuu Ginyoru no Nazo wo Oe_, and English fans usually call it either _Unthinkable Natural Law_ or _Hisoutensoku_.  12.8 is _Yousei Daisensou ~ Touhou Sangetsusei_, and English fans usually call it _Great Fairy Wars_, _Fairy Wars_, or (with tongue firmly in cheek) [_Faily Wars_](https://en.touhouwiki.net/images/4/4c/Th128FailyWarsTypo.jpg).  12.5 is _Double Spoiler ~ Touhou Bunkachou_, with an English title and Japanese subtitle.

Comment: @JustinTime You can edit that into the question if you'd like

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I don't have enough rep on Arqade to edit meta questions, unfortunately.

Comment: So what now? Does accepting an answer or renaming the tags happen first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is very similar to DCShannon's answer, but after thinking it over, I believe the most useful tags would be in the style of [touhou-eosd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-eosd), with a [touhou-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-6) alias. This style would be used for every game that uses the naming standard I've shown in the question body. For games where the subtitle would fit within the tag's limit, the full subtitle should be used, such as [touhou-mountain-of-faith](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-mountain-of-faith), while having a [touhou-10](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-10) alias.

For the games that fall outside of the naming standard, like the examples Justin Time provided, I think the most commonly used denomination should be used. So, those games would be:

- [touhou-hisoutensoku](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-hisoutensoku), with a [touhou-12.3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-12.3) alias.
- [touhou-double-spoiler](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-double-spoiler), with a [touhou-12.5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-12.5) alias.
- [touhou-great-fairy-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-great-fairy-wars) with a [touhou-12.8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-12.8) alias.

For existing tags, the retags will be:

- [touhou-eosd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-eosd) will stay as it is, and gain a [touhou-6](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-6) synonym.
- All questions tagged as [touhou-7](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-7) will be changed to [touhou-pcb](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-pcb), and the old tag will become a synonym of the new one
- All questions tagged as [touhou-7.5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-7.5) will be changed to [touhou-iamp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-iamp), and the old tag will become a synonym of the new one
- All questions tagged as [touhou-12.8-fairy-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-12.8-fairy-wars) will be changed to [touhou-great-fairy-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-great-fairy-wars), and the new tag will gain a [touhou-12.8](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/touhou-12.8) synonym.

Comment: +1 That also seems reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

I've never played these games. But, based on your info and comments, it sounds like the most important part is "touhou", the next most important part is the subtitle, which can be expressed as an acronym, and then finally the number may also be useful.

So, for you specific example, I would think

> touhou-6-eosd

would be best.

That will be found if any of the following are searched for:

- touhou
- touhou-6
- eosd

We can also add some synonym tags to help with search results.

Comment: Keep in mind that synonyms can be used to show up in search results, too.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yeah, of course. Let me add that.